# Get product information of items added in cart

Tags: magento

I need to get product's information in shopping cart. I mean to say if we add a product in cart I Need its Product ID and category ID of that item.

I want information of product attributes (e.g product's ID, Price, Parent id) whenever a product is added to cart at the shopping cart. How can I get that?

Comment: $catid =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getProduct()->
getCategoryIds($_item->getProductId()))->getName();

Comment: This code working perfectly in cart in order to find category id of certain product in Magento. After a good trashing i managed to find it out.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer? What happens when a product belongs to more than one category? What & where is `$this`? All of this is necessary for a good solution & good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$catid = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getProduct()-> getCategoryIds($_item->getProductId()))->getName();
```

I have written this code at /checkout/cart/item/default.phtml , You can follow the step it will work out surely.

This is the answer , will follow instruction accordingly Mr. benmarks. Actually I have just started posting stackoverflow. I am working on solution where this product in one or more categories.

Sorry if i have misinterpreted anything.